# Como saber si dos expresiones de crones se traslapan?

Tags: javascript

Tengo estas dos expresiones:

expresion1: 0 1 * * ? => 01:00 every day

expresion2: 0 1 ? * MON => 01:00 on Monday

Estas dos expresiones se traslapan (en el tiempo), ya que la expresion1 abarca todos los dias, incluyendo la expresion2. Mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de validar si expresiones de este tipo (incluyendo mas combinaciones) se traslapan entre ellas?. O si hay una libreria que me brinde las herramientas para ello. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Eso es un crontab correcto? En dicho caso, quieres evaluar esas expresiones con javascript/nodejs?

Comment: Hola  @Emeeus .No exactamente es un crontab, la evaluación si se hace con javascript, en base a una selección de eventos en un dropdown. Al escoger cualquiera de esos eventos (crones) quiero validar que no se traslape el seleccionado con los que ya se tienen agregados.

Comment: Esta bien, para el caso es lo mismo. Veo muy difícil hacer un algoritmo, sobre todo por la cantidad de variantes que hay.